# Unity and TFS Merging

Tags: unity, visual-studio, version-control

I'm trying to come up with a good Unity dev collaboration solution for a company where TFS is used as main version control system. I've setup the Unity projects to create metadata and store all as text. Like mentioned here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html

Then I enabled Unity's YAML SmartMerge for .unity and .prefab files in the Visual Studio Options like you can see in the below screenshot. I followed those instructions: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html

Now I tried all that and made a change in the Scene.unity on PC 1, checked it into TFS. Then a local change in Scene.unity on PC2 and used TFS Get Latest. But instead of merging the changes TFS showed the Resolve Conflicts screen only with the Take Theirs and Keep Mine options but no way to auto merge not even a manual merge option. :( The changes I did for testing where independent game objects and just a changes of their Position.x value in the Unity editor, so complete independent game objects. This should be easy to auto merge. 
I tried the same setup with SVN and GIT and it just worked automatically like expected. Only TFS seems not to trigger the merge at all when Get Latest is used.

Anything else I'm missing with the TFS and VS 2015 setup I'm using?

[image]

Comment: Hm, that's exactly how it should work. I've definitely seen this working with git & svn. Some people successfully used WinMerge & TortoiseMerge, cf.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5018646/2592915

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I checked out the blog post and changed it to TortoiseMerge with the cmd arguments as listed in the post just to see if it works. And it does not either. Diff works but no merge is triggered when Get Latest is called.

Comment: Ended up using GIT for this. ;)

Comment: git rulz anyway ;-)